# How do I delete one item from the list of 10 "recent documents" in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

How do I delete one item from the list of 10 "recent documents" in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there should be an easy, built-in way of doing this, but there's not (yet?). LibreOffice is now storing user settings and Recent Documents history in one file. On my system it is:

```
$HOME/.libreoffice/3/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

It is an XML document, and extracting the history of just one document is not straight forward.

There was a history plug-in (forgot the name) that used to work, but it no longer works for me. I created a script/one-liner to delete the entire recent documents history. It searches for and removes tags of the form: `<item ...HistoryInfo> ... </item>`

```
perl -i -pe 's#<item[^>]+?HistoryInfo.+?</item>##g' $HOME/.libreoffice/3/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

The usual disclaimers apply:

- always back up the file first
- understand a script before you execute it
- use at your own risk

Comment: This was useful in the past, and is instructive for automation, but the GUI can do it now.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the [Start Center](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/guide/startcenter.html) can do this out of the box.

You can see the Start Center when only one of the applications is running and no file is open. You may also launch it by running `libreoffice` in a terminal instead of one particular application (such as LibreOffice Calc or LibreOffice Writer).

Hovering over the thumbnails presents an "X" in the top right corner that can be used to delete the item.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one for LibreOffice 4.0x in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
perl -i -pe 's#<item[^>]+?HistoryInfo.+?</item>##g' $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

It works for me, but as stated before: use at your own risk.

Comment: I believe that some explanations on what this command is expected to do would be helpful to be able to understand the risk.